# iOS does not upload a music file to my server

Tags: php, objective-c, iis

I'm trying to upload a file from my iOS device to my IIS webserver (Windows Server Web 2008) but for some reason it does not receive the request if the added file is bigger than a certain size (around 10MB it seems).

I have made a couple more questions about this matter and found a lot of answers from these. I still have a problem with the bigger files not being sent. The previous cap was at 2MB, now it's somewhere around 10MB or so. All the settings in php that could have anything to do with this have been set to either 500MB or 6000 seconds timeout. The maxRequestBuffer for IIS has been set to 500MB aswell and should not be the problem.

Looking at what i have changed allready I would think the problem lies in the app side not sending it at all. Previously the request would be sent and received by the server and the code would be fired, but the file would be ignored as it was too big at that time. However right now when i have a big file the request will not be received.

My Objective-c code is like this:

```
NSString *theUrl = @"myserverurl";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];

[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];

NSTimeInterval timeOutSecs = 60000;
[request setTimeOutSeconds:timeOutSecs];

//[request setUploadProgressDelegate:(id)];

[request setFile:[soundFileURL path] forKey:@"mainfile"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

If anyone could tell me what is going wrong here it would help me alot! I couldn't find any methods allowing bigger files to be sent so any help on that would be great aswell! :)

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

After some testing it seems that 11.1MB (5minutes and 48 seconds of sound) is the very maximum. Any bigger than this will result in a failed upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two main areas to check:

1. On the web server, check the logs.
2. On the client, I've never used ASI synchronously, but if you switch to async, you can implement the `-requestFailed:` delegate method and analyze that error object in the debugger. (See the [how-to](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use))

Also look in the HTTP request/response headers and see if anything interesting turns up. HTTP Scoop is a useful tool for this if you are willing to part with $15. (I am not affiliated with the authors of HTTP Scoop.)

Also check any firewalls, filters, antivirus software, etc. between the client and the server.

Comment: Well first of all i dont get anything back from the server so i can't check the headers for the response. And i dont think the problem is a firewall of any sort as port 80 is completely open and it does work for smaller files..  Last of all i cant find the logs, so if you could tell me where the default location to find those is it would be awesome!

Comment: I checked and the app returns a null as the error. So i guess something goes wrong with the php code for some reason.. I wonder how/where to check the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

To find the logs in IIS
Open IIS Manager
Click on the Web SITE (not the virtual directory) that holds your site.
As you are on windows 2008 you will have IIS 7.0 or 7.5, so you should see the "Logging" option under the IIS group
Under Logging, there is a "Directory" option which is the path to the Logs

If the log doesn't give you enough information, select other types of logs or increase the number of fields outputted.
You may need to read Help to get an explanation of different fields.